# Generating unique ids from different data sources sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in 2 different sources. These different sources sometimes contain the same information between them so I want to group them and assign a unique new ID that consists of concatenating the source ids. To do this I use a join condition present in both sources. The problem is that sometimes one ID may have multiple "join conditions" assigned and this messes up my unique "master" id.

Example:

| Item | System1_id | System2_id | join condition | master_id | ideal_master_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item_1 | abc | - | a_unique_id | abc123 | abcxyz123 |
| item_2 | - | 123 | a_unique_id | abc123 | abcxyz123 |
| item_1 | abc | - | another_unique_id | abc987 | abcxyz123 |
| item_3 | - | 987 | another_unique_id | abc987 | abcxyz123 |

In my example above, all 3 items represent the same and should be grouped into a unique master_id. As you can see, item_1 has 2 join conditions assigned, this messes up the query because I am grouping by that condition, so the query takes them as different items.

My current situation is giving me master_id but I would want everything grouped correctly like shown in ideal_master_id.
The common denominator is item_1 that has both join conditions assigned and can be used (somehow) to bring everything together. I haven't been able to find a way to make this work.

One of my approaches was adding all the join conditions into an array and then comparing each join condition against the array and if it matches, concatenate the system id but I haven't been successful.

Any help is appreciated. I've been struggling with this issue for weeks and haven't found anything that works for my situation on the internet.

Comment: Could you please share an example of the array you are trying to use?

Comment: It's just an SQL array from bigquery created using ARRAY_AGG. It adds all the join conditions into said array.